# 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference when code run into (IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo)

Tags: java, android

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
    at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:1058)
    at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:658)
    at com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.b.b.b(DeviceInfo.java:50)
    at com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.b.b.a(DeviceInfo.java:115)
    at com.inmobi.ads.i.c(AdUnit.java:50471)
    at com.inmobi.ads.i.b(AdUnit.java:1835)
    at com.inmobi.ads.i.a(AdUnit.java:869)
    at com.inmobi.ads.ac.a(InterstitialAdUnit.java:566)
    at com.inmobi.ads.i$8.run(AdUnit.java:1631)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: @Alex You can write your question not only the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

@Alex You must be calling iterator() method on a null List, to avoid this you can have a 
list != null check and do your work inside it and handle the else condition with some smooth flow of printing error log or a toast.